# Perform Random Match to identify relationship between columns in different tables

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes with different column names in each dataframe and would like to do a random match by taking some values from each column, and match it to all columns in my list of dataframes. The purpose behind this is to identify which columns are linked (to allow easier merging after).

Does someone know a way to do this in R?

```
sales <- data.frame(r1 = c(10, 10.5, 30.1), r2 = c("ID1","ID2","ID3"))
purchases <- data.frame(cost = c(29.9, 11.5, 33.1), ID = c("ID1","ID2","ID3"), product_id = c("X1", "X2", "X3"))
product <- data.frame(admin_ID = c("X1", "X2", "X3"), name = c("ID1","ID2","ID3"))
```

From the data, you can see that Sales:r2 = purchases:ID = product:name AND Sales:product_id = product:admin_ID.

The match should only be performed on character variables.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the output you'r looking for? I cannot discern what it is you're specifically looking to get.

Comment: How would you match [floating-point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)? Should the match be between character variables only?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it will only be a match between character variables!

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian hmm, im not too sure how the output would look like, but would like to easily see the relationship between those columns that are linked to at least one other column from different tables

Comment: `anyDuplicated(sales$r2)` will show if `sales$r2` can be used as a primary key.